# Machine-specific emacs settings from a single config file?

Tags: emacs

I am using the same Emacs config on multiple workstations, synchronized via git. However, different workstations (and laptops) have different screen sizes and pixel densities and such, so I need to have a few settings that are specific to each machine. Is there a way to conditionally execute certain sections of my config only on certain machines, while still keeping the config file identical across all of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variables `system-name` and `system-type` will be helpful to you there; they let you write standard Lisp conditionals based on them.  `frame.el` also has various bits of code that *might* be helpful - `display-mm-width`, for example, theoretically returns the physical size of the display.

See `if` and `cond` in the elisp reference if you need the specific Lisp constructs to work out how to express the decision.

Comment: Thanks, `system-name` and `system-type` are what I was looking for.